# How to structure this data set?

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures

I am dealing with a set of fields, where each field has a display name and an internal name. For example:

- Due Date => DueDate
- Created By => Author
- Title => Title
- Author => Author0

Note that a display name can be identical to its internal name, or identical to another field's internal name (cf. above examples). The total number of fields is between 50 and 100.

I need the following methods:

- get internal name from display name
- get display name from internal name
- check if a display name exists
- check if an internal name exists

How should I structure the data to address these needs? The most straightforward seems to be to build two objects:

```
{"Due Date":"DueDate","Created By":"Author",...}
{"DueDate":"Due Date","Author":"Created By",...}
```

However I don't like the redundancy, and I am wondering if there's a better way. Other options I am considering:

Array of objects:

```
[{display:"Due Date",internal:"DueDate"},...]
```

Simple array:

```
["Due Date","DueDate","Created By","Author",...]
```

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), or maybe [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding with definite answers; Programmers is for discussions of design concepts and best practices. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82990/228805) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with an array of objects like this:

```
[{
    'display_name': 'Due Date',
    'system_name': 'DueDate',
    'value': ''
}, {
    'display_name': 'Created By',
    'system_name': 'Author',
    'value': ''    
}, {
    'display_name': 'Title',
    'system_name': 'Title',
    'value': ''        
}, {
    'display_name': 'Author',
    'system_name': 'Author0',
    'value': ''    
}]
```

Its very extensible with the option to add extra parameters and is easily send-able through JSON.

If you feel this data structure is too wordy you can always make the keys minified like the example below and then convert it into the proper structure in your front end logic:

```
{
    'a': 'Due Date',
    'b': 'DueDate',
    'c': ''
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting an extensible structure, I know the field might have other properties like the data type. However my use case is just a switch and won't go beyond that. I am actually getting the data in that form, and trying to restructure it for my specific purpose.

Comment: Marking it as answer. Another good point is that it's easier to share/send a single object than 2.